# MongoDB Storing varying interval timeseries data in one collection

Tags: mongodb, database-design, time-series

I have weather data coming from various sources (api, iot measurements), which are in different granularities (daily, hourly, minutes).

You can imagine my data to look like:

```
2022-01-01 | source:api | data..
2022-01-01 01:00 | source:api | data..
2022-01-01 02:00 | source:api | data..
2022-01-01 00:30 | source:iot | data..
2022-01-01 01:00 | source:iot | data..
2022-01-01 01:30 | source:iot | data..
2022-01-02 | source:api | data..
```

Depending on the service, I sometimes need my data in a daily resolution, sometimes hourly.
My initial ideas were to store them in either:

- time buckets grouped by day, e.g.:

```
2022-01-01
[d]
[h1, h2,..]
[m1, m2, m3 ...]
2022-01-02
[d]
[h1, h2,..]
[m1, m2, m3 ...]
```

- Save a resolution (daily, hourly, minute data) variable for every document.

I wonder what the best data design strategy would be that would also work long term.

Some additional things to consider:

- The data is also used by user facing services (e.g. api) and requests can be many a day. However, these requests are targeted at specific resolution/sources. Calls where we combination of data will be used a few a day.
- Sometimes there is a precedence of which source we will choose based on presence. E.g. use minute iot data, otherwise daily api data.

Comment: Scale and access patterns are the two things to consider, what is the scale of requests? 10 a day? millions a day?
From an access pattern perspective if you need hourly resolution how are you considering the "daily" documents. are they being used for that query? if you don't "mind" outlier queries the best way would be to add 0 values to hour/minute for missing. values. that will obviously affect queries for those times.

Comment: I am attempting to build for scale but any aggregated call will be few a day (e.g. transforming hourly data to daily). User facing requests (which are many) wil be resolution/source specific. I am not sure what you mean by adding 0 values to hour/minute, what would that solve?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to let the data in the database "explain itself" clearly without special hidden knowledge.   I suggest you keep it clear and simple by storing each incoming item with a true `datetime` type (not an ISO-8601 string) *and* a "resolution enum" to indicate what the timestamp actually means.   `2020-06-22T00:00:00Z` without the enum field is ambiguous.